# How to disable break line after ')' in methods and after class name when formatted content in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I have the following class definition before formatted content.

```
class MyClass {
  public function __construct() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

After formatted content.

```
class MyClass
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I am using PhpStorm 2018. When I formatted lines with `Ctrl+Alt+L`. How to disable this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The brace placement is based on your code style settings.

To keep the opening brace on the same line, go to your settings under `Editor->Code Style->PHP`, and change the braces placement for "In function declaration" to "End of line".

This will change the placement when automatically formatting a selection with `Ctrl+Alt+L` as well as when generating functions from templates (pubf, etc.).